# Concatenar datos de un usuario e imprimirlos una sola vez

Tags: php, sql

Estoy trabajando en scriptcase y manejo fpdf para generar reportes, pero tengo un problema.

Intento imprimir en una sola línea los datos del usuario, por ejemplo:

```
id ------nombre----------------- datos --------------fecha1 -------fecha2

1 ------ david puc poot ---------dato1,dato2,dato3- 15/dic/2016 15/enero/2017

2------ felipe cabrebra santos--- dato1,dato2,dato3,dato4-- 15/dic/2016 15/enero/2017
```

sin embargo no logro hacerlo.
Estoy manejando este código:

```
foreach({rs} as $info){
    if($estPaciente != $info[0]  ){
        $estPaciente = $info[0];
        $servicio->CellFitScale(15,0,utf8_decode($info[0]),0,0,'L');
        $servicio->CellFitScale(125,0,utf8_decode($info[5]),0,0,'L');
        $servicio->CellFitScale(20,0,utf8_decode($info[1]),0,0,'L');
        $servicio->Cell(20,0,utf8_decode($info[2]),0,0,'L');
        $servicio->Ln(5);
    }

    if($estPaciente == $info[0]  ){
        $servicio->CellFitScale(100,0,utf8_decode($info[4]),2,0,'L');
        $servicio->Ln(5);
        $flag = true;
    }

}//fin de foreach
```

con este código logro hacer esto

```
id --------- nombre -------datos--------- fecha1----------- fecha2

1 ----------david puc poot------  15/dic/2016---- 15/enero/2017

--------------------------dato1

--------------------------dato2

---------------------------dato3


2 ----------Felipe Cabrera------  15/dic/2016---- 15/enero/2017

--------------------------dato1

--------------------------dato2

---------------------------dato3
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, ha de ser sencillo pero no logro averiguar cómo.

Mi SQL me arroja este resultado :

```
id*********nombre********descripcion*******fecha1***********fecha2

1**********david puc poot*********dato 1*******15/12/2016******17/01/2017

1**********david puc poot*********dato 2******15/12/2016******17/01/2017

1**********david puc poot*********dato 3*******15/12/2016******17/01/2017

2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 1*********15/12/2016******17/01/2017

2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 2***********15/12/2016******17/01/2017

2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 3*********15/12/2016******17/01/2017

2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 4**********15/12/2016******17/01/2017

2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 5**********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
```

para ordenarlos  debo hacer que el campo `descripcion` se concatene siempre que el usuario sea el mismo,
para que al momento de imprimir sólo aparezca una vez el usuario y los datos del campo `descripcion`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido , puedes agregar el error que obtienes? que ocurre en tu caso que falla?

Comment: Es concatenar los datos, de un usuario e imprimirlos

Comment: Es concatenar los datos, de un usuario e imprimirlos de esta forma: id ------nombre----------------- datos --------------fecha1 -------fecha2

1 ------ david puc poot ---------dato1,dato2,dato3- 15/dic/2016 15/enero/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `GROUP_CONCAT` te permite concatenar cadenas en las consultas agrupadas.

**Concatenar descripción por nombre**

```
SELECT nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM _nombreTabla_ 
GROUP BY nombre
```

**Concatenar descripción por nombre y fecha**

```
SELECT nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion SEPARATOR ' '), fecha1, fecha2 
FROM _nombreTabla_
GROUP BY nombre, fecha1, fecha2
```

Comment: Gracias, como gbd uso interbase en la version 2.0 y he visto un nueva actualizacion que permite el uso de list muy parecido al group_concat.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes concatenar los campos de tu select y simplemente lo mandas a llamar, ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT ('nombre', 'dato1', 'dato2') AS Result;
```

El resultado de mi sql es este:

```
id*********nombre*************descripcion************fecha1******fecha2

1**********david puc poot*********dato 1***********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
1**********david puc poot*********dato 2 *********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
1**********david puc poot*********dato 3***********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 1 ********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 2 ********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 3 *********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 4 *********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
2**********felipe cabrera*********dato 5 *********15/12/2016******17/01/2017
```

para ordenarlos  debo hacer que el campo `descripcion` se concatene siempre que el usuario sea el mismo
para que al momento de imprimir sólo aparezca una vez el usuario y los datos del campo `descripcion`.